# VLC and Snap-Store is not opening and showing error permission denied in ubuntu 20.04

Tags: permissions, snap, vlc

I try to open vlc or snap-store but they are not opening.
After trying to open through terminal, I got the following errors that shown below.
Error for vlc:

```
snap run vlc
/snap/vlc/1700/bin/desktop-launch: line 51: /home/jd81197/.config/user-dirs.dirs: Permission denied
Error: unable to open display :0
VLC media player 3.0.11 Vetinari (revision 3.0.11-0-gdc0c5ced72)
xcb_connection_has_error() returned true
[000056540703fd50] vlcpulse audio output error: PulseAudio server connection failure: Connection refused
ALSA lib conf.c:3916:(snd_config_update_r) Cannot access file /usr/share/alsa/alsa.conf
[000056540704bbe0] main interface error: no suitable interface module
[0000565406f73b40] main libvlc error: interface "globalhotkeys,none" initialization failed
[0000565406f73b40] main libvlc: Running vlc with the default interface. Use 'cvlc' to use vlc without interface.
[000056540704bbe0] skins2 interface error: cannot initialize OSFactory
[0000565406f703c0] main playlist: playlist is empty
[000056540704bbe0] [cli] lua interface: Listening on host "*console".
VLC media player 3.0.11 Vetinari
Command Line Interface initialized. Type `help' for help.
```

Error for snap-store:

```
snap run snap-store
/snap/snap-store/467/snap/command-chain/desktop-launch: line 50: /home/jd81197/.config/user-dirs.dirs: Permission denied
sed: can't read /home/jd81197/.config/user-dirs.dirs: Permission denied
/snap/snap-store/467/snap/command-chain/desktop-launch: line 238: /home/jd81197/.config/user-dirs.dirs: Permission denied
cp: cannot open '/home/jd81197/.config/user-dirs.locale' for reading: Permission denied
/snap/snap-store/467/snap/command-chain/desktop-launch: line 243: /home/jd81197/.config/user-dirs.locale: Permission denied
realpath: '': No such file or directory
realpath: '': No such file or directory
realpath: '': No such file or directory
realpath: '': No such file or directory
realpath: '': No such file or directory
realpath: '': No such file or directory
realpath: '': No such file or directory
realpath: '': No such file or directory
cp: cannot stat '/snap/snap-store/467/gnome-platform/usr/share/mime': No such file or directory
/snap/snap-store/467/snap/command-chain/desktop-launch: line 20: /snap/snap-store/467/gnome-platform/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-3-0/gtk-query-immodules-3.0: No such file or directory
ERROR: /snap/snap-store/467/gnome-platform/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-3-0/gtk-query-immodules-3.0 exited abnormally with status 127
Directory '/home/jd81197/snap/snap-store/467/.local/share/mime/packages' does not exist!
ERROR: update-mime-database /home/jd81197/snap/snap-store/467/.local/share/mime exited abnormally with status 1
/snap/snap-store/467/usr/bin/snap-store: error while loading shared libraries: libgdk_pixbuf-2.0.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Can anyone please share some insights about how to fix these permission denied error.

Answer (score 0):

For most X11 gui apps you can export the same DISPLAY variable of the user running the Xserver and run `xhost +` as this user to permit other users accessing the Xserver. 
For snap you have to add the `export DISPLAY=$YourDisplayValue` to the users .bashrc running the snap command.
I cant remember how to do this value programatically to be more portable but its not changing that much usually.
Apparently passing environment to snap apps is a bit of a mission.
But this worked for me on a current 20.04